# Как склонять мужскую фамилию с беглой гласной?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Тупо по прецеденту, индивидуально или есть правило?

Фамилия известная - режиссёр Влади́мир Ильи́ч Макера́нец.

> Фильмы Владимира Макеранца.
>
> «Золотой полоз» — фильм режиссёра Владимира Макеранца по мотивам
>   уральских сказов Павла Бажова.
>
> «Ты есть» — фильм режиссёра Владимира Макеранца рассказывает непростую
>   историю взаимоотношений невестки и свекрови.

Нашла и сохранённую "е":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Бельчиков Ю. А. Практическая стилистика современного языка, 2012.**

В фамилиях на **ЕК, ОК** гласный обычно сохраняется: Мазурок — Мазурока, Чапек — Чапека.

В фамилиях на **ЕЦ** гласный выпадает: Грицевец — Грицевца.

В фамилиях на **НЕЦ/НЦ** буквенный состав сохраняется: Баренц — Баренца, Лоренц — Лоренца. Сравнить: Уманец — Уманеца, Уманц — Уманца.

**Тогда правильно: Макеранец - Макеранеца.**

Answer (score 1):

Мужские фамилии восточнославянского происхождения, имеющие беглую гласную, при склонении могут образоваться двумя способами – с потерей и без потери гласной при склонении: Заяц – Заяца – Заяцем и Зайца – Зайцем. Необходимо учитывать, что при заполнении юридических документов такие мужские фамилии нужно склонять без потери гласного.

Мужские фамилии западнославянского и западноевропейского происхождения, имеющие беглую гласную, склоняются без потери гласной: улица Слашека, романы Чапека, в исполнении Карела Готта, лекции Завранека. 
http://vsefamilii.ru/vsefamilii-sklonmujfam.html

Получается, что лучше склонять без потери гласного, не ошибётесь, ведь это абсолютно верно при заполнении документов. Хотя фамилия явно восточнославянская, возможно и так, и так.